# An equivocal probability question

Tags: probability

Suppose $F$ and $F^{\prime}$ are two absolutely continuous cumulative distribution functions. What is the probability of $F^{\prime}\left[ F^{-1}(x)\right]=x$? I first thought this is a zero probability event since the only way of this, $F=F^{\prime}$, but, then, what is the point of absolute continuity in this question? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Since $F^{-1}(x)=x$ is not a number (but a property, fulfilled or not), the expression $F'[F^{-1}(x)=x]$ is meaningless.

Comment: @Did: Apologies,my mistake! I made the correction.

Comment: OK. Next problem: since nothing is random in the question, asking for a probability seems absurd. And what is this $x$?

Comment: Well the thing is basically $x$ is random variable and $F$ and $F^{\prime}$ denotes, let's say, what I believe about this distribution and what the I believe about some other guy believes about this distribution. So, what is the probability of what I believe about this disribution is same with what I believe you believe about this distribution.

Comment: Hmmm... $F^{-1}(x)$ can exist only if $x$ is in $[0,1]$ hence, do you assume the random variable $X$ is $[0,1]$ valued with CDF $F$ and asking for $P[A]$ where $A$ is the event $A=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=F'(F^{-1}(X(\omega))\}$? Then I am afraid that $P[A]=1$ if $F'=F$ and that $P[A]=0$ otherwise--so there is not much point to this question, is there?

Comment: I think there is. For random variable $X$ suppose that I believe a normal distribution what is the probability that I think that you also believe exactly the same distribution. This seems a zero probability event to me, because we are talking about continuous function spaces. Does this sound right?

Comment: To tell you the truth, the interpretation of the question in terms of comparison of two CDFs that you seem to invoke is mysterious to me. But the maths in the question are summarized in my last comment--with the not-too exciting answer I explain.